# Is there a built-in in twisted for branching a deferred's result into another deferred chain that doesn't affect the initial deferred's results?

Tags: python, api, twisted, deferred

I have a deferred that fires a result. I want to give this result to several functions that consume it. The simple way to do this is to add callbacks to the deferred. However, if one of the functions happens to not return the same result, then the functions added later will get a different result, which I don't want. To solve this issue I had to do the following:

```
def branchDeferred(d):
    #return a deferred which returns d's results without affecting them
    branchD = defer.Deferred()
    def success(result):
        branchD.callback(result)
        return result
    def failure(fail):
        branchD.errback(fail)
        return fail
    d.addCallbacks(success, failure)
    return branchD
```

Observe the distinction:

```
>>> resultD = defer.Deferred()
>>> resultD.addCallback(printCallback)
<Deferred at 0x2a3bcb0>
>>> resultD.addCallback(printCallback)
<Deferred at 0x2a3bcb0>
>>> resultD.callback("lovely")
Result: lovely
Result: None
```

vs:

```
>>> resultD = defer.Deferred()
>>> branchDeferred(resultD).addCallback(printCallback)
<Deferred at 0x2a2ada0>
>>> branchDeferred(resultD).addCallback(printCallback)
<Deferred at 0x2b658a0>
>>> resultD.callback("lovely")
Result: lovely
Result: lovely
```

Is there any nicer way to do this with built-in twisted idioms, i.e. is there something I have not understood about deferreds? Or is this the only way to do it?

In case you're wondering, this came up because I was using `defer.inlineCallbacks` which consumes the result of a yielded deferred instead of propagating it.

EDIT: This code demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
>>> class Baz:
        def __init__(self):
            self.resultD = defer.Deferred()

        @defer.inlineCallbacks
        def fooMe(self, name):
            result = yield self.resultD
            print "fooMe(%s) got: %s" % (name, result,)
            defer.returnValue(result)


>>> b = Baz()
>>> d1 = b.fooMe("one")
>>> d2 = b.fooMe("two")
>>> b.resultD.callback("SHINIES")
fooMe(one) got: SHINIES
fooMe(two) got: None
```

This code in `_inlineCallbacks()` in `twisted/internet/defer.py` is the culprit:

```
        def gotResult(r):
            if waiting[0]:
                waiting[0] = False
                waiting[1] = r
            else:
                _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)

        result.addBoth(gotResult)
```

`gotResult` does not `return r` at the end. As I don't want to patch my twisted install to get this to work, I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do the work-around.

Comment: maybe your function decorated with `defer.inlineCallbacks` misses `defer.returnValue(result)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: no, it returns the result. but even so, that concerns a different deferred - the one related to the function, not the one related to the deferred it yields

Comment: do you mean you can't use `x = yield f1(result); y = yield f2(result); ...`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: no, see my edit

Comment: [the same thing happens without `defer.inlineCallbacks`](https://gist.github.com/7e0e709f6e5415786300/db916edfb4842042211e6009cd4053f62cd9bbda). So your intent is to fork the deferred to fan out result something like `tee` utility?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yep, exactly

Comment: Twisted deferred mechanism is designed to be a way of delivering [point-to-point][1] async messages. One producer, one consumer. This is entirely intentional.

You seem to need a different kind of usage, [the publish-subscribe][2] , which is not builtin in Twisted. Please note that there's no "better" way to do something, it's just a design choice.

  [1]: http://www.eaipatterns.com/PointToPointChannel.html
  [2]: http://www.eaipatterns.com/PublishSubscribeChannel.html

Comment: I ended up answering a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995565/re-using-deferred-objects-in-twisted/27996359?noredirect=1#comment44383098_27996359 - sorry I didn't notice this one when it was asked!